# Sending Values from Class to WPF Window in the background

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listener

I have a WPF window which contains a 'textbox status console' that displays what's happening in the background while the program is running. For example, when the program saves data to the database, the console should display "Saving Data. Saving complete".

However all the processes (such as saving data, retrieving data) is all done through different classes and the WPF C# Window is separate.

Class A:

```
public void SaveData()
{
     //Save Data
     //Print a success message in Window's Textbox
}
```

In the meantime, another process could print another message as well. This should all happen in the background. I believe that the Window needs to have a Listener and every time a message is sent, it needs to print it in the textbox. What is the method that I should use?

I know I can do this:

```
string message = SaveData();
consoleBox.Content = message;
```

But several other classes work independently and does not follow a step by step procedure all the time, instead they print a message as soon as they receive values, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to have a static listener object that is in charge in writing to the "console".

Everybody can send that object messages when they need to , and he is in charge of writing them out (either appending or replacing the text, dunno what you need).

If you're using MVVM Light, there's a messaging framework that does basically that. You can register a class to listen for messages, and then whenever you send a message of that type, it will handle it.

Here's some code from a project I wrote :

```
/// <summary>
/// Global class used to set the status message
/// </summary>
public static class StatusSetter
{
    public static void SetStatus(string s)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new StatusMessage(s));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Holds the status message.
/// </summary>
public class StatusMessage
{
    public StatusMessage(string status)
    {
        NewStatus = status;
    }

    public string NewStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And to use simply register:

```
/// Use this to set the status from any view/viewmodel
Messenger.Default.Register<StatusMessage>(this, Messenger_ReceiveMessage);
```

which simply calls the following message:

```
/// <summary>
/// Receives new status via the StatusMessage class received by the messenger.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="status"></param>
private void Messenger_ReceiveMessage(StatusMessage status)
{
    StatBarTextProp = status.NewStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have bind the textbox text to a global static property in your system.
if you don't already have, create a GLOBALS static class, there you can put global helpers like you need here.
Then bind your element to this property, through static binding (you can find it here in stackoverflow somewhere, tell me if you cant find it)